# How to sort results by string length on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sql-order-by

I can do it easily on mysql

```sql
select * from TABLE order by length(FIELD) asc
```

How can I do it on MongoDB?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647644/select-string-length-in-mongodb if you want it to be efficient, I'd store the length of the string and sort with that.

Comment: @MagnusTengdahl, I tried to do mapreduce to produce another collection with a new column to store the string length and then sort by that field. But the map reduce is not fast and take around 1000ms for 20,000 rows and I need to create a new collection everytime I do sorting.

Comment: I second WiredPrairie's response - store the string length as a separate field in the document and sort on that.

Comment: probably a project and then sort

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select string length in mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647644/select-string-length-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 26):

MongoDB 3.4 introduces the [`$strLenCP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenCP/) aggregation operator that finally supports this. An example:

```javascript
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        {$project: {
            "field": 1,
            "field_length": { $strLenCP: "$field" }
        }},
        {$sort: {"field_length": -1}},
        {$project: {"field_length": 0}}
    ]
)
```

Comment: Can you show how its work in js code, i tried to do something similar but is doesn't work?

Comment: This worked like a charm; thanks [@zohar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2017661/zohar-bar-yehuda) (Though as a MongoDB beginner myself, it might've been nice to note that the `"field"` key must refer to an _extant_ field in the document, and explain that the `"field_length"` key is customizable, since it's calculated on demand.)

Comment: Note the filed must exist otherwise it will cause `"errmsg" : "$strLenCP requires a string argument, found: missing",`

Comment: If you want the whole document and not just a subset of the fields, I'd recommend the [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-addFields) operator rather than the first `$project` operator, as it will retain all existing fields in addition to adding the new one. `{$addFields: { "field_length": {$strLenCP: "$field"}}}`

Answer (score -3):

suppose your schema is something like:

```
example = {_id: "XXX", text: "YYY"}

db.example.aggregate([
 {$project : {text : 1, length : {$size : "$text"}}}, 
 {$sort : {length : 1}}
]);
```

I think this will do the job, but only for mongo 2.6 and above

Comment: $size is for arrays, not strings, so that will not work.

Comment: uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
 "errmsg" : "exception: The argument to $size must be an Array, but was of type: String",
 "code" : 17124,
 "ok" : 0
}