# is it possible to use "$where" in mongodb aggregation functions

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I need to get the length of a string value in MongoDB using aggregation functions.

it works in

```
db.collection_name.find({"$where":"this.app_name.length===12"})
```

but when implanted to

```
db.collection_name.aggregate({$match: 
                                 {"$where":"this.app_name.length===12"}
                                 },
                             {
                             $group :
                                  {
                                  _id : 1,
                                   app_downloads : {$sum: "$app_downloads"}
                                  }
                             }

);
```

I got this result:

```
failed: exception: $where is not allowed inside of a $match aggregation expression
```

The question is:  is it possible to use $where in aggregation functions?
or is there any way of getting the length of a string value  in aggregation function?

Thanks in advance
Eric

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select string length in mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647644/select-string-length-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't support **$where** in aggregation pipeline and hope this will never happen, because JavaScript slows things down. Never the less, you still have options:

1) Мaintain additional field(e.g. app_name_len) than will store **app_name** length and query it, when needed.

2) You can try *extremely slow* MapReduce framework, where you allowed to write aggregations with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Today I had the same problem.

Mongodb doesn't support this.app_name.length, but you can do this condition with **$regex** - this is not very quick, but it still works.

```
{"app_name": { $regex: /^.{12}$/ }}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve the behaviour expected of OP would be chaining up `$expr` with `$strLenCP`

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      12,
      {
        $strLenCP: "$app_name"
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wAKOlQkC1R7)